# The value of PageWidth doesn't work for saving as HTML?

Tags: export, bugs, html

```
CellPrint@Cell["Test","Text",PageWidth->300,Background->Red]
```

And I got this snippet of HTML code：

```
<p class='Text' style='background-color: #FF0000;'>
Test
</p>
```

No `width` value, and also in the `.css` file, there is no value `width:300px;`

Is this a universe question?

I've also tried using a stylesheet with `PageWidth`, sometimes it works, I'm not sure.

Comment: Since this question has garnered no other attention I am marking it as a bug, unless and until someone wants to argue that it is not.